# 2 COUNT dentro de um SELECT com LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, count

Tenho duas tabelas:

usuarios:

```
id | nome | email
```

envios:

```
id | id_envia | id_recebe
```

Toda vez que um usuário envia um cartão (que vai por e-mail) a um outro usuário, marca nessa tabela, e toda vez que recebe também marca.

**A dúvida:**

Quero fazer um SELECT nos usuários e na resposta saber quantas vezes ele estava no **id_envia** e quantas vezes ele estava no **id_recebe**, tentei algo assim:

```
SELECT usuarios.email, COUNT(envios.id_recebe) AS numeroRecebe, COUNT(envios.id_envia) AS numeroEnvia
FROM usuarios 

LEFT JOIN envios ON usuarios.id = envios.id_envia OR usuarios.id = envios.id_recebe

GROUP BY usuarios.email
```

O problema é que tanto o **numeroRecebe** quanto o **numeroEnvia** estão retornando o mesmo valor, a soma dos dois... onde estou errando?

Comment: Caio, conseguiu resolver?  Caso não tenha resolvido, o banco de dados é o Sql Server?

Comment: Deu certo ou ainda precisa de ajuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função de agregação COUNT conta o número de linhas da tabela, portanto COUNT(id_recebe) ou COUNT(id_envia), não vai fazer diferença neste caso, pois a tabela tem o mesmo número de linhas nos dois casos.

Para conseguir um número diferente você deve fazer duas consultas diferentes, onde cada uma terá uma quantidade de linhas correspondente ao número de recebimentos ou de envios conforme o necessário. Depois você pode juntar as duas consultas com um JOIN e ter o resultado desejado.

Código para criar as tabelas e acrescentar alguns exemplos:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` (
      `id` int NOT NULL,
      `nome` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
      `email` varchar(40) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `envios` (
      `id` int NOT NULL,
      `id_envia` int NOT NULL,
      `id_recebe` int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO usuarios (id, nome, email) VALUES (1, "José", "jose@gmail.com");
INSERT INTO usuarios (id, nome, email) VALUES (2, "Ricardo", "ric@outlook.com");
INSERT INTO usuarios (id, nome, email) VALUES (3, "Gabriel", "gabriel@hotmail.com");

INSERT INTO envios (id, id_envia, id_recebe) VALUES (1, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO envios (id, id_envia, id_recebe) VALUES (2, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO envios (id, id_envia, id_recebe) VALUES (3, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO envios (id, id_envia, id_recebe) VALUES (1, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO envios (id, id_envia, id_recebe) VALUES (1, 3, 1);
```

Consulta calculando números diferentes de envios e recebimentos:

```
SELECT recebidos.id, recebidos.numeroRecebe, enviados.numeroEnvia
FROM
    (SELECT usuarios.id, COUNT(envios.id_recebe) AS numeroRecebe
    FROM usuarios LEFT JOIN envios ON (usuarios.id = envios.id_recebe)
    GROUP BY usuarios.id)  recebidos
JOIN
    (SELECT usuarios.id, COUNT(envios.id_envia) AS numeroEnvia
    FROM usuarios LEFT JOIN envios ON (usuarios.id = envios.id_envia)
    GROUP BY usuarios.id) enviados
ON (recebidos.id = enviados.id)
```

Pode testar que funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei qual banco você está utilizando, mas segue um exemplo em SQL Server:

```
    SELECT 
        A.email,
        SUM(B.id_envia) AS [Total de envios],
        SUM(B.id_recebe) AS [Total de recebidos]
    FROM usuarios  AS A
        INNER JOIN envios AS B
        ON A.id =   B.id
GROUP BY A.email
```

As colunas que você precisa saber o total são somadas `SUM()` e agrupa por `email`.

Answer (score -1):

O COUNT retorna o numero de linhas, por isso retorna o mesmo valor. Como você quer saber a quantidade de vezes que enviou e quantidade de vezes que recebeu então deve usar o sum, conforme abaixo:

```
select a.id, a.nome, 
sum( b.id_envia ) as enviados, 
sum( b.id_recebe ) as recebidos 
from usuarios a left join envios b
on a.id = b.id
where a.id = 1
group by a.id, a.nome
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas não foi, ele parece que está usando o número do ID, tipo, um usuario tem ID 12, ele soma esse valor, estranho...

Comment: Faça um select simples nas duas tabelas: 
  
         select top 10 * from usuarios where id = 1 
         select top 10 * from envios where id = 1

Claro, considerando que id = 1 exista, e poste o resultado para eu
ver o conteúdo das tabelas para replicar igualmente aqui